# Lights have no effect when placed inside a building Blender 2.82?

Tags: light

I need for a personal project a scene with a church, so I [found a free church interior](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/old-church-modeling-interior-scene-eb6cf543aa7d45e3acee49887ae3135c)

The problem is that, after opening the model in Blender, if I try to put any lights inside of church, the lights have no effect. No matter which type of light I choose, there is no light in render, whether I choose Cycles or EEVEE.

Would some of the more advanced users from you download the scene and see where is the problem?

If, for example, I go outside of church and put a cube, the lights have effect on cube, but on exterior or interior of the church there is no effect.

My specs are:

- Windows 10
- Hpz820 PC - 2 xeon  total 12 cores
- 96 gb ram
- Blender 2.82

Comment: can u post image

Comment: Put the camera inside and then render.

Comment: Even with the camera inside, there is no light

Comment: Here it is an immage , where the size of the spot light is huge, intesity likewise, but with no result

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oX1HMjJ6MJVY3CmqlUylVbvuWoBUwjSp/view?usp=sharing

Thank you very much for the responses so far :)